# Strange error while installing packages on python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

There is this very strange exception kinda thing happenning when I am trying to install package. I am using the command prompt to locate Python directory (python34) and then run the pip command after locating it to the required directory where the packages are kept. Anyone has an idea. Maybe its stupid, but its frying my brains here.

```
C:\kushal\DataMining\Python Packages> C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install C:\kushal\DataMining\Python Packages\setuptools-18.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl

You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 7.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 232, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 305, in run
    name, None, isolated=options.isolated_mode,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 181, in from_line
    isolated=isolated)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 54, in __init__
    req = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse(req)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2873, in parse
    reqs = list(parse_requirements(s))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2820, in parse_requirements
    "version spec")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 2785, in scan_list
    raise ValueError(msg, line, "at", line[p:])
ValueError: ('Expected version spec in', 'C:\\kushal\\DataMining\\Python', 'at',
 ':\\kushal\\DataMining\\Python')
```

Comment: What is the exact command you ran to generate this traceback, and what directory were you in when you ran it? Also, did you upgrade `pip` as recommended to see if the problem goes away?

Comment: Also, please adjust your command prompt window so the full width of the error message is printed, then [edit] your question with the output. It's kind of unreadable at the moment.

Comment: Yes I upgraded the pip. I get the exception on running below command.         
    C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install C:\kushal\DataMining\Python Packages\setuptools-18.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl

FYI: C:\kushal\DataMining\Python Packages is the location where I have downloaded all the packages. In the above I am trying to install setup tools package, but the problem is same for numpy, scipy and every other package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because you didn't use quotes to enclose the path in your command. It should have been:

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install "C:\kushal\DataMining\Python Packages\setuptools-18.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl"
```

Or, you could just run

```
C:\Python34\Scripts>pip install setuptools-18.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
```

since you're already **in** the `C:\kushal\DataMining\Python Packages` directory, you don't need to spell it all out again.

Finally, to save yourself some time, add `C:\Python34` and `C:\Python34\Scripts` to the beginning of your path. Now, you can just run `python program.py` or `pip install packagename.whl` directly without adding the full path every time.

Answer (score -1):

Open command prompt as an administrator. **Run**>Pip install --upgrade pip.
CD to your directory. Setup your tools.